# MVC 5 send radio button string value to post action method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've read a couple of questions and answers on this matter but none of them gets me any closer to solving this issue. My problem is I can't seem to retain the `RadioButtonFor` checked value to the post action method. It's alot of unrelated stuff so i'll try to boil it down to the related issue.

So I've got a `ViewModel` like this:

```
    public class QEventHandlerVM
    {
       //Removed unrelated
       public QueueEventHandlerModel QEventHandler { get; set; }           
       public string SelectedOption { get; set; }
    }
```

The `Get Method` for the edit view. I'm setting the `SelectedOption` here so I can work with it on the frontend. The task is to show and hide div depending on the `SelectedOption` value. This part is working as far as I know, the value gets set and is used in the view via jQuery.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            //Removed unrelated...
            QueueEventHandlerModel model;
            QEventHandlerVM vm = new QEventHandlerVM();

            ApiCommunicator.Get("QueueEventHandlers/" + id, out model);

            vm.QEventHandler = model;
            if (...)                
                vm.SelectedOption = "toQueue";

            if (...)                
                vm.SelectedOption = "redirection";

            if (...)
                vm.SelectedOption = "hangup";

            return View(vm);
        }
        catch (HttpResponseUnsuccessfulException e){...}

    }
```

The `Edit view` simplified:

```
        @model Foo.WebSites.Web.Views.QueueEventHandlers.QEventHandlerVM

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            //Unrelated stuff...
            @Html.HiddenFor(s => s.SelectedOption)

            @Html.RadioButtonFor(s => s.SelectedOption, "toQueue", new { id = "rdToQueue", @class = "q-event" })
            <label for="rdToQueue">Transfer call to queue</label>

            @Html.RadioButtonFor(s => s.SelectedOption, "redirect", new { id = "rdRedirect", @class = "q-event" })
            <label for="rdRedirect">Transfer call to destination</label>

            @Html.RadioButtonFor(s => s.SelectedOption, "hangup", new { id = "rdHangup", @class = "q-event" })
            <label for="rdHangup">Hangup</label>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Save</button>
        }
```

The `Post` method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(QEventHandlerVM model, int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {... return View(model); }

        if (model.SelectedOption == "hangup" || model.SelectedOption == "redirection")
        {
            model.QEventHandler.QueueId = null;
        }
        else if (model.SelectedOption == "toQueue")
        {
            model.QEventHandler.Phrase = string.Empty;
            model.QEventHandler.Redirection = string.Empty;
        }
        else if (model.SelectedOption == "hangup")
        {
            model.QEventHandler.Redirection = string.Empty;
            model.QEventHandler.QueueId = null;
        }

        try {// Update}
        catch (HttpResponseUnsuccessfulException e){...}
    }
```

Now, here the `SelectedOption` value is the same as it was from the `Get` method. There's probably something simple I've missed and there's most likely some better way to go about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe a typo but the second radio button should be `"redirection"` not `"redirect"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have a `HiddenFor` **and** associated edit fields for your `SelectedOption` property. Simply remove the `HiddenFor` and that should work:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(s => s.SelectedOption)
```

Comment: @brroshan No problems glad I could help!